# grunt-autoprefixer and grunt-postcss not working

Tags: gruntjs

I have tried both plugins [grunt-autoprefixer](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer) and [grunt-postcss](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss) but neither are adding prefixes. I have tried with something that caniuse.com says requires a prefix (cursor: grab).

Here is my autoprefixer task:

```
   autoprefixer: {
        dev: {
            no_dest: {
                src: 'dev/styles.css'
            }
        },
        live: {
            no_dest: {
                src: 'live/styles.css'
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my postcss task:

```
   postcss: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                processors: [
                    require('autoprefixer-core')({browsers: 'last 1 version'}).postcss
                ]
            },
            dist: {
                src: 'dev/styles.css'
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you give it a try with following grunt packages

- [grunt-postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-postcss)
- [autoprefixer-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer-core)

and following snippet

```
postcss: {
  options: {
    processors: [
      require('autoprefixer-core')({browsers: 'last 1 version'}).postcss
    ]
  },
  single_file: {
    src: 'src/main.css',
    dest: 'css/main.css'
  },
  multiple_files: [{
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    src: 'src/css/*.css', // -> src/css/file1.css, src/css/file2.css
    dest: 'dest/css/' // -> dest/css/file1.css, dest/css/file2.css
  }]
}
```

Comment: How can I dev multiple files instead of just `main.css`?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss#usage), the configuration is different, try it:

```
postcss: {
    options: {
        processors: [
            require('autoprefixer-core')({browsers: 'last 1 version'}).postcss
        ]
    },
    dist: {
        src: 'dev/styles.css'
    }
}
```

Comment: I am simply adding a dev task for this. I have tried it without this and still the same result.